# Compare two strings in x86 assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, string-comparison

I want to compare two strings in x86 assembly. One of them is read from a file and the other one is read from keyboard and both are saved in a variable.

I have no idea how to compare these two variables. I'll be so excited if someone would give me an example or something that can help me.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

includelib msvcrt.lib
include Macro.asm

extern exit: proc
extern printf:proc
extern scanf:proc
extern strlen:proc
extern fscanf:proc
extern fopen:proc
extern fprintf:proc
extern fclose:proc
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

public start


.data
format_sir db "%s", 0
format_afisare  db "%s", 0
format_zecimal db "&d", 0
mod_citire db "r",0
mod_scriere db "w",0
pointer_fisier_sursa dd 0
pointer_fisier_destinatie dd 0
nume_fisier db 20 dup(0)
fpass db 20 dup(0)
fuser db 20 dup(0)
user db 20 dup(0)
pass db 20 dup(0)


.code
start:


    ;read file name
    citire_fisier:
    push offset nume_fisier
    push offset format_sir
    call scanf
    add esp,8


    ;open the file in read mode
    deschide_fisier_citire nume_fisier, mod_citire, pointer_fisier_sursa

    cmp pointer_fisier_sursa,0   
    jne citire_user_parola   
    jmp citire_fisier 



    citire_user_parola:
    ;read from file
    Push offset fuser 
    Push offset format_sir 
    Push pointer_fisier_sursa
    Call fscanf
    Add esp,12

    push offset fpass 
    push offset format_sir
    push pointer_fisier_sursa
    call fscanf
    add esp,12

    ;read from keyboard
    push offset user
    push offset format_sir
    call scanf
    add esp,8

    push offset pass
    push offset format_sir
    call scanf
    add esp,8
```

Macro.asm :

```
 deschide_fisier_citire macro nume_fisier, mod_deschidere, pointer_fisier_sursa

    push offset mod_deschidere
    push offset nume_fisier
    call fopen
    mov pointer_fisier_sursa ,eax
    add esp,8
endm


inchidere_fisier macro pointer_fisier_sursa

    push pointer_fisier_sursa
    call fclose
    add esp,4
endm
```

Comment: To compare strings, use `rep cmpsb`.

Comment: Where are the string variables that you want to compare? The only string I see is "nume_fisier" (because it is type `db 20 dup`).

Comment: You're right. I was wrong in declaration. I need to compare fpass with pass and fuser with user.

Comment: Ral, @pirela has edited their answer, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HLA (High Level Assembly ) :more on http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/Linux/HTML/StringInstructions.html

```
cld();  
mov( AdrsString1, esi );  
mov( AdrsString2, edi );  
mov( 7, ecx );     # 7 is the length of the comparison ie size of strings  
repe.cmpsb();
```

In a more classical way :

```
mov ecx,7      
cld           
mov esi, offset [stringA]  
mov edi, offset [stringB]  
repe cmpsb     
cmp ecx,0
je strings_are_equal
```

Comment: This is non-standard syntax. It is apparently part of Randy Hyde's HLA language. That could be very confusing for someone actually trying to learn x86 assembly!

Comment: Putting aside whether or not I agree that learning a subtly different language is actually going to help you learn the language you want to learn quickly, it doesn't make for a very good answer to this question.

Comment: `cmp ecx,0` - error here. this is produce wrong result if different only in last symbol. need just `je strings_are_equal` after `repe cmpsb`